# Android- how do I know what methods should run on the main thread?

Tags: android, view, thread-safety

I know there is an annotation @MainThread sometimes,
but not in all cases.

For example, in the view class, how do I know if a method can or cannot and should or should not be called from the main thread or I can call it from a computational thread?

Answer (score 1):

Everything on that has to do with the app's UI should be run in the main thread, otherwise you'll very likely get an `Exception`.

To answer your question more specifically, you probably want to make sure you call anything inside a view directly from the main thread.  But again, when in doubt, try it out, and you'll get an exception if you're doing anything wrong.

A few way to move functionality into the main thread is using the `Looper. getMainLooper()`, or using Kotlin coroutines with the `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher.